# Bind dynamic columns and data to mat table in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

Am binding data to angular material table by preparing columns dynamically.

```
please find below code 

component.ts

export class DepComponent {
    tableSource :any= [
              {
                "name":"ssit",
                "departments":[{"depName":"cse","noOfStudents":30},
                                {"depName":"civil","noOfStudents":60}]
              },
                   {
                "name":"vbit",
                "departments":[{"depName":"cse","noOfStudents":90},
                                {"depName":"civil","noOfStudents":40}]
              }
        ];

    displayedColumns: string[] = [];
   constructor() {
        this.displayedColumns= this.tableSource[0].departments.map(x=>x.depName)
    }
}


  <table mat-table [dataSource]="tableSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                {{column}}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <span *ngFor="let s of element.departments">
                    {{s.noOfStudents}}
                </span>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

am getting output like this, duplicate data is printing in each row like below with my code

```
cse     civil
30 60   30 60
90 40   90 40
```

i want output like below

```
Cse Civil
30  60
90  40
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz where I can reproduce an issue!

Comment: You have to manage both rows and column as separate array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired result First you will need to transform data in desired format like

```
dataSource=this.tableSource.map(i=> {
      var result = {};
         i.departments.forEach(d=>{
        result[d['depName']]=d.noOfStudents
        })
       return result;
      })
```

then change html to

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
         <ng-container matColumnDef="cse">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cse </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cse}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="civil">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Civil </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.civil}} </td>
          </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pl9jzp)

Comment: it's working for sample JSON what I provided, when i fetch result from database result returning as {"30":"30","60":"60"} value is retunrning instead of key

Comment: @madhuGoud check your api response if that is same as sample json

Comment: correct @jitender invalid response from my api, one thing is it possible to push object here result[d['depName']]={d.noOfStudents,d.noOfTeachers }

Comment: @madhuGoud I don't think so bcs it  need to be string and your are trying to assign object